# how to can completely delete component DotNetBar from Visual Stuio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, dotnetbar

I installed DotNetBar 12.9, but i want Uninstall it and after that install DotNetBar 12.8.6 how can i do it?

i did all of levels from here [How to perform clean install of DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=47), but didn't delete component.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to firstly close all open Visual Studio instances. Then uninstall dotnetbar from programs & files. In all your projects that you used dotnetbar you have to delete obj and bin folders. Then do clean and rebuilt. To remove toolbox of dotnetbar just right click on it and remove.